# Specifying size of custom action on Display Form (in SPD)

Tags: list-form, sharepoint-designer, custom-action

I have a custom action in the following location:
"Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Actions.Controls._children". Even though I've purposely only selected a 16x16 image to be used, the 32x32 image is what is rendered. I want this link/image to show up near "workflows" and "alerts" in the smaller grouping of the "Actions" section. Is there a way to enforce that in SPD? I've tried changing the location to go deeper, but I don't see a good resource showing any other options below "._children" on MSDN.

Here is an image for context: [image] 
The custom action I add will appear in the "Actions" section, but it looks like the "Edit Item" button instead of the "workflows" buttton.

Comment: do you have the xml definition of your custom action?

Comment: This is an "OOTB" custom action created through SP Designer. I'm not sure there is a way to figure out what the XML definition is behind the scenes.